# GSRPC: Check transaction failed?

Tags: transactions, events, golang

**Context:** We are using GSRPC for interacting with a Polkadot Node. We are sending transactions using [SubmitAndWatchExtrinsic](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v3@v3.0.2/rpc/author#Author.SubmitAndWatchExtrinsic).

**Question:** How can I detect if the transaction failed?

---

Note: I am aware that the [ExtrinsicStatusSubscription](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v3@v3.0.2/rpc/author#ExtrinsicStatusSubscription) reports about the status of an extrinsic. However, it does not seem to report whether the transaction failed during execution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing indeed, since extrinsics in Substrate don't "fail" in the error case.
Extrinsics will emit an `ExtrinsicFailed` event when returning an error, but still execute fine.
This stands in contrast to Ethereum, where a transaction reverts and does not execute in the error case.

In general you have to wait for the extrinsic to be included in a block.
Then read the events of your extrinsic from that block. There should either be a `ExtrinsicSuccess` or `ExtrinsicFailed` event.
GSRPC has some rough edges, I don't think it exposes everything that is necessary for this approach.

Another "hacky" way of doing it; Wait for the event that would be emitted in the success case with a timeout.
If it times out, you know that it did not work. In the other case it could also be that someone else send a successful extrinsic, whos event you now see.

Comment: Hi Oli, thanks for the reply. I've seen that I can subscribe to `EventSystemExtrinsicFailed` events. However, I don't see a way how to identify which transaction / extrinsic they belong to.